# R add column dataframe if dataframe contains X variables

Tags: r

How can I conditionally add one column to a dataframe is that dataframe has X number of columns?

Say I have several dataframe, some with 5 columns, others with 6, and I want to add one empty column to the ones that have 5?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function which create a new column when your dataframe doesn't have 6:

```
MyFunction <- function(df){
  if(ncol(df == 5)){
    df <- df %>% 
      mutate(newcol = NA)
  }
  else{
    df <- df
    }
}
```

Then, create a list of your dataframes:

```
mylist <- list(df1,df2,...)
```

Then, you can use `lapply` to create columns on all your dataframes

```
lapply(mylist, MyFunction)
```

Comment: Thks @MonJeanJean, can you tell me how can I list all dataframes that have X columns?

Comment: I'm note sure to understand. You want the names of the dataframes or the dataframes themselves @AnEostig?

Comment: Yes, later in my project I have to make a list of all dataframes with X columns, reason why I asked you directly